# Generic parameterised type return generates warning or error

Tags: java, generics, java-11

In the example code below I'm trying to return but at the very least I get a warning. The other scenarios (2 and 3) result in an error. Is there a correct way to return that does not result in a warning?

```
    static class Cars<C extends Car> {

        private C c;

        Cars(C c) {
            this.c = c;
        }
    }

    static class Car { }

    static <C extends Car> Cars<C> cars() {
        // 1. WARNING: 'Raw use of parameterized class 'Cars''
        //      return new Cars(new Car());
        // 2. ERROR: 'Cannot infer arguments'
        //      return new Cars<>(new Car());
        // 3. ERROR: 'Required C provided Car'
        //      return new Cars<C>(new Car());
    }
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Results in error: "Required type: Cars <C> Provided: Cars<Car>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misusing, or at least misunderstanding, generics here. It is very important to understand that generic parameters are decided by the *caller* not the callee.

From the implementation of your `cars` method, you seem to want to return a `Cars<Car>` object, but your method signature says otherwise. Your method signature says

> this method can return a `Cars<C>` where `C` is `Car` or any subclass of `Car`, and you, the caller, gets to decide what `C` is.

Your method doesn't do that, does it? If I wrote a subclass of `Car` called `Lorry`, can your method give me a `Cars<Lorry>`? Nope.

(And before you say it, no, a `Cars<Lorry>` is not "a kind of" `Cars<Car>`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po) if you don't understand why.)

So you need to change the signature to a more "humble" one :) (without the generic parameter)

```
static Cars<Car> cars()
```

And use this line as the return statement:

```
return new Cars<>(new Car());
```

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I think you are right! There's a lot of generics at the class level (which I omitted to simplify the example) which I started off trying to reuse but as a static utility method it does not have access to those. So I think changing the method sig to a more 'humble one' is the right thing to do.